# How to use Berkeley-ABC model checker?

Tags: verification, model-checking

I install the Berekeley-abc model checker that you can find in this address click [here](https://github.com/berkeley-abc/ext-hello-abc)

but I don't know how to use it and also I cant find any good example of this model checker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~alanmi/abc/) in Programming notes part there are 3 files to start with ABC model checker